# Can Apache Drill connect to Amazon RedShift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, apache-drill

Can Apache Drill connect to Amazon RedShift ? If yes Can anyone help me with configuration and plugin for Apache  Drill to connect to Amazon RedShift .

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming or development. Perhaps you should try [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Additionally,  questions asking for book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource recommendation are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get the example from @pavel to work. i am sure it has to do with the driver name and which specific driver i downloaded and installed.

However, I was able to successfully connect to AWS Redshift using the following steps.

Navigate to folder you have downloaded drill to:

```
cd ~/Downloads/apache-drill-1.11.0
```

download the required jdbc drivers from AWS at [Download the Amazon Redshift JDBC Driver](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html)

save the jar files into the folder ~/Downloads/apache-drill-1.11.0/jars/3rdparty

start drill using:

```
./bin/drill-embedded
```

Navigate to http://localhost:8047/storage to configure a new data source aka plugin.

Create a new storage plugin and name your data source accordingly. for my test i called it redshift.

Once you have named the source as "redshift", then paste the correct configuration

```
{
  "type" : "jdbc",
  "driver" : "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver",
  "url" : "jdbc:redshift://redshiftserver.mydomain.net:5439/databaseName?ssl=true&sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory",
  "username" : "username",
  "password" : "password",
  "enabled" : true
}
```

next test connectivity to the server using the following query

```
select * from redshift.autonation.information_schema.columns
```

Comment: one thing that tripped me up is the qualified name to your tables. In the case that redshift is what you named your connection the query would read: `redshift.<database_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name>` for your queries to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, just use [Example-Postgres-Configuration](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/#Example-Postgres-Configuration)

And then use web gui to add a storage:

```
{
  "type" : "jdbc",
  "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver",
  "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://URL:5439/DB_NAME_HERE",
  "username" : "user",
  "password" : "password",
  "enabled" : true
}
```